# For-based loop for large number of QMenus

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-c++

being a noobie with `Qt` I couldn't figure out how to create
a vector of `QMenu`.

Using `C++` I got the following (simple) idea:

`std::vector<QMenu> *subMenus;`

and then use a `for-loop` to create a certain number of menus.

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); ++i)
{
   subMenus[i] = new QMenu('some name',MainMenu);
   MainMenu->addMenu(subMenus[i]);
}
```

Where the size of List is a large number (~40).
The problem is that in doing this I face the following error message refering to the index `i`:

`expression must have a constant value`.

I am not sure if I should use append or push back to subMenus to avoid this error.

Thanks

Comment: You were probably after `std::vector<QMenu*> subMenus;`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
QVector<QMenu*> menuVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
{
   auto* menu = new QMenu('some name', MainMenu);
   menuVector.push_back(menu );
   MainMenu->addMenu(menu);
}
```